# How to avoid for-loop while using append()

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

First of all, I apologize for being an absolute beginner in both python and numpy. Please forgive my ignorance.

I have a 4D cube of pressure measurements where the dimensions are (number of samples, time, y-axis, x-axis), which means, for each sample, I have a 3D cube of spatio-temporal profile. I need to collect the pressure readings of this 3D cube (time, y-axis, x-axis) and store it into an array for each sample only where the coordinates satisfy a specific condition. Upon varying the specific condition, the size of this array will vary too. So, I have to use append() to build this array. However, since say for 1000 samples, I have to search through more than a millions coordinates using For-Loop for each sample, the code I have written is pretty inefficient and takes a lot of time to run (more than several hours). Can you please help me to write it more efficiently?

Below is the code I've tried to solve the problem. It works nicely and gives expected result but it is extremely slow.

```
import numpy as np

# Number of sample points in x,y and t-axis
Nx = 101
Ny = 101
Nt = 100
n_train = 1000
target_array = []

for i_train in range (n_train):
    for k in range (Nt):
        for j in range (Ny):
            for i in range (Nx):
                if np.round(np.sqrt((i-np.round(Nx/2))**2+(j-np.round(Ny/2))**2)) == 2*k:
                    target_array.append(Pressure[i_train,k,j,i])
```

Comment: How does it work nicely? You overwrite *target\_array* in the outer loop, so at the end it will only contain the values corresponding to `i_train = 999`.

Comment: Extremely sorry for the mistake, I made an error while copying the code from my file. I have corrected it. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Comment: First you could try to extract all possible (e.g. `np.round(Nx/2)`) operations outside of the (inner) loops. This will get you some time improvements but at a max factor of 10. Then you could use vectorized operations (*np* specific) to reduce the time to seconds (probably).

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. I apologize for my ignorance, but can you please explain this sentence a little bit detail: "Then you could use vectorized operations (np specific) to reduce the time to seconds (probably)"?

Comment: What @CristiFati means is that you should try and use numpy arrays' built-in capability for performing vectorized operations, instead of relying on Python's for-loops, which are extremely poor performance wise. I'll try and sketch out a solution for you.

Comment: Now I got it. Thank you so much. @Jethro Cao

Comment: @BahauddinOmar Glad to hear. So are you good now, or do you still need help?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I went to sleep. Yes, I am good now. Again, Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the condition involves the indexes and not the values of your 4D array, you can vectorize it using [numpy.meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html).

Here `pp` is your 4D array:

```
iv, jv, kv = np.meshgrid(np.arange(pp.shape[3]), np.arange(pp.shape[2]), np.arange(pp.shape[1]))
selecting = np.round(np.sqrt((iv - np.round(pp.shape[3]/2))**2 + (jv - np.round(pp.shape[2]/2))**2)) == 2*kv
target = pp[:,selecting]
```

Provided that I've understood correctly how your 4D array is organized:

- the arrays created by `meshgrid` hold the indexes to select `pp` elements on the 3 dimensions x, y, t.
- `selecting` is a boolean array created by replicating your equation, to check which coordinates satisfies the condition.
- `target` is a selection of `pp`, taking all element on 0 axis which satisfies the condition (i.e. `selecting` is True) on the other 3 axes.

Note that `target` is a 2D array, to have a 1D array, use `target.flatten()`.